# Why pattern matching does not throw exception in Maybe monad

Tags: exception, haskell, monads

My question is simple. Why wrong pattern matching  does not throw exception in Maybe monad. For clarity :

```
data Task = HTTPTask {
 getParams   ::  [B.ByteString],
 postParams  ::  [B.ByteString],
 rawPostData ::  B.ByteString 
}  deriving (Show)

tryConstuctHTTPTask :: B.ByteString -> Maybe Task
tryConstuctHTTPTask str = do
 case decode str of
    Left _  -> fail ""
    Right (Object trie) -> do
        Object getP    <- DT.lookup (pack "getParams")   trie
        Object postP   <- DT.lookup (pack "postParams")  trie
        String rawData <- DT.lookup (pack "rawPostData") trie
        return $ HTTPTask [] [] rawData
```

Look at **tryConstuctHTTPTask** function. I think that when the pattern does not match (for example "*Object getP*") we must get something like "*Prelude.Exception*", instead i get the "*Nothing*". I like this behavior but i am not understand why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doing `pattern <- expression` in a `do`-block, will call `fail` when the pattern does not match. So it is equivalent to doing

```
expression >>= \x ->
case x of
  pattern -> ...
  _ -> fail
```

Since `fail` is defined as `Nothing` in the `Maybe` monad, you get `Nothing` for failed pattern matches using `<-`.

Comment: @Anton: You can find it in the source for the [`Data.Maybe` module](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Data-Maybe.html), but the definition is simply `fail _ = Nothing`.

Comment: i did not find there pattern matching process. Only (Just x) >>= k      = k x

Comment: i want to see source code which defines such behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @Anton: As my answer explained, there are two behaviours relevant here: a) In the `Maybe` monad `fail foo` returns `Nothing`. The source code that defines this behaviour is simply `fail _ = Nothing` in the instance declaration for `Monad Maybe`. b) A failed pattern match using `<-` calls `fail`. This behaviour is defined in [the Haskell standard](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html)'s section about translating `do` expressions.

Comment: @Anton: If you want to see the source code which implements the translation specified in the standard, you'll have to dig into the `ghc` source code (or the source code of whichever Haskell compiler you're using).

Comment: Thanks. The Haskell standard  it is that i wanted. I found the next definition: do {p <- e; stmts} = let ok p = do {stmts}
    ok _ = fail "..."
  in e >>= ok